# Multiply value by the previously calculated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a forecast model and am stuck automating the trend over time in sql. What I'm trying to do is multiply each row by a previously derived number and then multiply the next row by the calculated previous row. Here is a basic visualization;

```
date          num_reqs  cumulative_value   cumulative value formula                                           
2019-10-01  246.4   276                  num_reqs * 1.12     
2019-10-02  246.4   309        previous cum_value * 1.12
2019-10-03  246.4   346        previous cum_value * 1.12
2019-10-04  246.4   388        previous cum_value * 1.12
2019-10-05  246.4   435        previous cum_value * 1.12
```

I've tried a few variations of lag() but I don't think lag allows for cumulation. I've also tried exp() but it doesn't work with my values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use exponentiation to do this.  I think you want:

```
select t.*,
       numreqs * power(1.12, row_number() over (order by date)) as cumulative_value
from t
```